# Error when building source files with wxWidgets , Linux, C++

Tags: c++, linux, build, wxwidgets

I tried to build a source file with following command:

```
g++ main.cpp `wx-config --cxxflags --libs std`

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgthread-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXxf86vm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSM
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtk-3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk-3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpangocairo-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcairo-gobject
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcairo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexpat
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I guess I didn't install wxWidgets correctly (I installed libwxgtk3.0-dev as described in multiple install tutorials)

EDIT

```
wx-config --libs std
-L/usr/local/lib -pthread   /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_qa-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu_net-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_html-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_adv-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_core-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu_xml-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu-3.1.a -pthread -lgthread-2.0 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lSM -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lpng -lexpat -lwxregexu-3.1 -lwxtiff-3.1 -lwxjpeg-3.1 -lz -ldl -lm
```

Comment: You do not have the glib2 development package correctly installed. You do not have the various X development packages installed. You're missing a bunch of stuff.

Comment: Is there any kind of bundle package or will I have to install everything one by one? I have wxWidgets working on another PC and can't remember having lost that much time installing it...

Comment: You did not specify which Linux distribution you are using. These are standard packages that are available to be installed in every major Linux distribution. Check your Linux distribution's documentation for more information.

Comment: I am using Debian Ubuntu 14.04 . I couldn't find any of the missing packages in the official sources. It is strange because I installed wxWidgets on the same Distribution not long time ago

Comment: You didn't look hard enough. Just a few minutes of Googling [finds the glib2 development package for 14.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libglib2.0-dev). I'm sure all other packages are also available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Ubuntu, you really shouldn't have any problems if you just installed the [distribution package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libwxgtk3.0-dev).

It looks like you had tried to install wxWidgets from sources before and your `wx-config` comes from `/usr/local/bin` and is *not* the one installed by the package. You can check it using `which wx-config` and/or using full path to `/usr/bin/wx-config` when compiling. Just get rid of this one, and all the other traces of wxWidgets under `/usr/local`, if you're using the system packages.

Comment: I retyped the output on my mobile phone and forgot a dash. I edited my original question because of the limited comment size

Comment: I updated the answer taking into account the new information.